# Show that $X^n-p$, for p prime, is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that, for any prime $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$, $X^n-p$ is irrededucible over $\mathbb{Q}$. (We haven‘t looked at stuff like the Eisenstein‘s criterion yet in class.)

I was able to show that for any $m<n$: $p^{m/n}\notin \mathbb{Q}$, but now I don‘t know what to do, I suppose I could write out a general polynomial division but there surely must be a better way.

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Did you learn Gauss's lemma?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569356/xn-a-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq might help you.

Comment: You asked for help; you got help; now what? Are you OK, Henry?

Comment: Oh I‘m sorry, was busy and forgot to check in on stackexchange again, I’m OK hahah:) The post you linked to makes a lot of sense and solved my issue, thanks!